# insert dynamic data into QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

I want to populate a `QTableWidget`with incoming data from user input

this function should insert each incoming input  row by row in "real time" , so far its inserts the input in all rows at the same time
what am I missing here ?

```
 @qtc.pyqtSlot(str)
    def add_dynamicdata(self, data):
        row = 0
        col = 0

        for i in range(self.table_widget.rowCount()):
            # insert inputdata in all cells at the same time !
            cell = qtw.QTableWidgetItem(str(data))
            self.table_widget.setItem(row, col, cell)
            row += 1
```

full code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""


"""

import sys
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc



class LambdaTableWidget(qtw.QWidget):

    # signals
    core_signal = qtc.pyqtSignal(str)



    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)



        # position
        qtRectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = qtw.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())
        # size
        self.resize(1400, 710)
        # frame title
        self.setWindowTitle("QTableWidget Test")

        # heading
        heading_label = qtw.QLabel('better then excel')
        heading_label.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignHCenter | qtc.Qt.AlignTop)

        # add Button
        self.setdata_button = qtw.QPushButton("insert data")
        self.test_button = qtw.QPushButton("test feature")




        # table Widget
        self.table_widget = qtw.QTableWidget(5, 1)

        # name colums, rows
        colum_label = ["Weight"]
        row_label = ["row 1", "row 2", "row 3", "row 4", "row 5"]

        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(colum_label)

        self.table_widget.setVerticalHeaderLabels(row_label)


        # layout
        self.main_layout = qtw.QGridLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(heading_label, 0, 0)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.table_widget, 1, 0)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.setdata_button, 2, 0)


        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        self.show()

        # functionality
        self.setdata_button.clicked.connect(self.start)



    def start(self):
        # starts thread
        # Setting thread.daemon = True will allow the main program to exit before thread is killed.
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, daemon=True).start()
        self.core_signal.connect(self.add_dynamicdata)


    def _execute(self):
        while True:
            user_input = input("type in: ")
            self.core_signal.emit(user_input) # transmit data

    @qtc.pyqtSlot(str)
    def add_dynamicdata(self, data):
        row = 0
        col = 0

        for i in range(self.table_widget.rowCount()):

            # todo fix the bug !!!
            # insert inputdata in all cells at the same time !
            cell = qtw.QTableWidgetItem(str(data))
            self.table_widget.setItem(row, col, cell)
            row += 1




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = LambdaTableWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't understand where is your doubt. You're using a for loop that cycles through the row count of the table, so it's pretty obvious that it will fill the table with the same data. Also, you should use Qt's own threading (via QThread) as mixing it with Python's threading might give unexpected results. Finally, if you want user input in a GUI based program, you should use a GUI based interface to do that, and not `input`.

Comment: @musicamante can you provide a solution if the cause of the behavior is obvious to you

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_dynamicdata(self, data):
    row = 0
    col = 0

    for i in range(self.table_widget.rowCount()):
        # insert inputdata in all cells at the same time !
        cell = qtw.QTableWidgetItem(str(data))
        self.table_widget.setItem(row, col, cell)
        row += 1
```

Data doesn't change in this contest
so  `cell = qtw.QTableWidgetItem(str(data))` would remain the same for all iterations